# AngularJS 2 as Frontend and Symfony 3 as backend

Tags: angularjs, symfony, angular

I will start a new project with angularjs and symfony 2.

I just wanna know if my way, how I will realise it, is good.

The AngularJS frontend would be available over https://www.example.com and the backend of symfony would be under https://api.example.com.

So I hope that the routing of every framework would not colidate.
And I have also a available API for the mobile Devices.

Is this a best practice or is it better to use the api under https://www.example.com/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO it is better to create 2 separate **projects**.

- for the api (api.example.com)
- for the front-end (example.com)

This way you avoid problems with:

- routing (like you point - collisions)
- sessions (api do not need sessions at all)
- packages - e.g. your api could use symfony 3.1, but your front-end symfony 2.7
- easier load balancing (IMO)

see:
[Is it better to place a REST API on a subdomain or in a subfolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554943/is-it-better-to-place-a-rest-api-on-a-subdomain-or-in-a-subfolder)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer